# How do you remove/change labels of widgets on ipywidgets Interact feature?

Tags: python, label, interactive

In the following example:

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import numpy as np

from bokeh.models import Slider

from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 2000)
y = np.sin(x)

p = figure(title="simple line example", plot_height=300, plot_width=600, y_range=(-5,5))
r = p.line(x, y, color="#2222aa", line_width=3)




def update(f, w=1, A=1, phi=0):
    f.title='fdsafdsafewa'
    if   f == "sin": func = np.sin
    elif f == "cos": func = np.cos
    elif f == "tan": func = np.tan
    r.data_source.data['y'] = A * func(w * x + phi)
    push_notebook()

show(p, notebook_handle=True)


interact(update, f='Hi there!', w=(1,5), phi=(0, 20, 0.1))
```

The graph produced is as follows:
[image]

Currently, the variables w, a and phi assigned to the sliders show up to the left of the slider as labels. Is there a way to remove them, or change the labels in a manner which doesn't involve editing their variable names in the interact section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, `interact` is not part of Bokeh at all, it is part of the `ipywidgets` library. In any case the labels are taken from the function parameter names, so you only need to change them however you like, e.g.

```
interact(update, Omega=1, Amplitude=1, Phase=0):
```

Comment: In this case, I want my labels to be two words, for example "Phase Shift" instead of "Phase." Since function parameter names do not accept spaces, is there a way to change label titles without using the function parameter names? Thanks

Comment: From the ipywidgets documentation, it looks  like you would have to create widgets manually to configure an arbitrary description https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html